# Removing Spotlight

Tags: macos

Is it possible to remove spotlight from the menu bar? I have too many menu bar items running all the time and I'm trying to remove what I can to see everything regardless of what app is open.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by running a command in the terminal: `sudo chmod 600 /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search`.  Then logout and back in.

[Source](http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/12/hide-spotlight-menu-icon-mac-os-x-lion/).